# In C++ how do i validate a file or folder path?

Tags: c++, windows

A user input string for a destination path can potentially contain spaces or other invalid characters.

Example: " C:\users\username\ \directoryname\ "

Note that this has whitespace on both sides of the path as well as an invalid folder name of just a space in the middle. Checking to see if it is an absolute path is insufficient because that only really handles the leading whitespace. Removing trailing whitespace is also insufficient because you're still left with the invalid space-for-folder-name in the middle.

How do i prove that the path is valid before I attempt to do anything with it?

Comment: Why do you need to? What's so bad about just trying to open it, and letting it fail?

Comment: That's obviously a windows path, but what dev environment are you in? plain old C++ (like gcc), Visual C++, Managed C++ ?

Comment: upvote for the clear question, e.g. "... whitespace on both sides ..."

Comment: The answer is the BOOST File System: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young You might want to check if a path is well-formed but not actually want to create the file or directory specified (e.g. validating user input before accepting said input).

Answer (score 6):

The only way to "prove" the path is valid is to open it.

[SHLWAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559(VS.85).aspx) provides a set of path functions which can be used to canonicalize the path or verify that a path seems to be valid.  This can be useful to reject obviously bad paths but you still cannot trust that the path is valid without going through the file system.

With NTFS, I believe the path you give is actually valid (though Explorer may not allow you to create a directory with only a space.)

Comment: Exactly.  I don't see what "validity" constraints this violates.  It's asking for a direcotry named "directoryname" inside a subdirectory of "username" named " ".  If there are application-specific validity constraints, they'll need to be coded in the application.  And in any case, simply calling fopen() on the path with the appropriate arguments is enough to tell you whether you can, y'know, open it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library provides helpers to manipulate files, paths and so... Take a look at the [simple ls example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp) and the *exists* function.

Answer (score 1):

I use GetFileAttributes for checking for existence. Works for both folders (look for the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY flag in the returned value) and for files. I've done this for years, never had a problem.

Comment: Thye one obvious point where this method fails is of course when you're validating paths that don't exist yet, e.g. before attempting to create a directory.

Comment: If it doesn't exist yet the path isn't valid. Validating a path as *possibly* valid is a different problem from validating a path as valid. Depends what the OP means by "valid" of course.

Comment: Please check [How do I find out if a path specifies an actual file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692009/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-path-specifies-an-actual-file); it says for a connection string this simply returns `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE`, so how to distinguish that from files using just `GetFileAttributes`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to open the file you can also use something like the [`access()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/access.html) function on POSIX-like platforms or [`_access()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx) and friends on Windows.  However, I like the Boost.Filesystem method [Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008707/in-c-how-do-i-validate-a-file-or-folder-path/2008940#2008940) pointed out.