# How do I find out if a path specifies an actual file?

Tags: c++, sql, c, windows

I have a function as follows:

```
DWORD stats = GetFileAttributesA(path);
return (stats != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) && !(stats & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) ? 1 : 0;
```

The problem is that a SQL Connection string: "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=localhost;database=NorthWindDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;" somehow is valid. It returns 32 (stats is 32 when that input is given) which is the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE value. I cannot filter this out because other legitimate files also return that value.

How do I determine whether the value specifies a file or connection string?

UPDATE: PathFileExists doesnt work either

Comment: Can you trace the actual return value? Despite my mistake in my deleted answer I still think that the condition is faulty. You are only checking if the returned value is not valid and does not have `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` set. It might still have others set.

Comment: yes, as I listed, the return value is 32 (not -1)

Comment: Ok, this is not my day, sorry.

Comment: If you try reading 1 byte from the file, does that work for connection string too? Something along the lines of File.Open(path).read(1) or similar.

Comment: @dutt, nope, fgetc returns -1. But this doesnt help since I cant differentiate between that and an empty file.

Comment: Are you sure it is not actually checking a real file?  You should run process monitor to see what file is actually being accessed.  Also, you didn't mention what OS this happens on.

Comment: chacham: Well, you didn't specify that the file needed to contain anything. But you could combine read() with checking the file length then.

Comment: @Luke, how could it check a real file? what file would it be checking? there certainly is no file in that directory with that name.

Comment: @dutt I could do that, but I still wouldnt be able to differentiate a real but empty file from this other non real file.

Comment: Are you sure?  The only way I could reproduce your behavior was to create a file named "Driver=...".  Use Process Monitor to see if it is actually accessing a file on disk somewhere.

Comment: chacham: I thought those two went in the same category for you. What exactly do you want? Check if it's a valid file path or check if it's an existing file or something else?

Comment: @dutt yes I want to know if its a file, not some wierd other thing

Comment: Either a file with that name exists or you are passing something else to GetFileAttributes().  Try this.  Put a call to CreateFile() for that file then MessageBox() to pause execution.  Run Process Explorer, find your process, and show open handles in the lower pane view.  If what you say is true, there should be a handle for "Driver=..." showing where the file is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all else seems to fail, here is a completely different approach: try `system("dir \"path_to_check\"")` and check its return value (works on my machine :) See also [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/).

Answer (score 1):

How about [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FindFirstFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

> Searches a directory for a file or
>   subdirectory with a name that matches
>   a specific name (or partial name if
>   wildcards are used).

and

> If the function fails or fails to
>   locate files from the search string in
>   the lpFileName parameter, the return
>   value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

I think it can be used to tell if a given string represents a real file or not.

Comment: That function is used to iterate a directory for its file contents, doesnt really help in this scenario

Comment: "Searches a directory for a file or subdirectory with a name that matches a specific name (or partial name if wildcards are used)." and "If the function fails or fails to locate files from the search string in the lpFileName parameter, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE". I think it can be used to tell if a given string represents a real file or not.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of similarities with [how do i validate a file or folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008707/in-c-how-do-i-validate-a-file-or-folder-path), where they also mention [BOOST Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html), but I have no experience with that…

Comment: all the suggested functions state that it is valid

Comment: Well, it actually IS a valid file name. Doesn't [_access()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx) work? Or how about your own little sanity check, then? (How come you are checking connection strings here?)

Comment: Maybe [GetFileAttributesEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364946.aspx) will give you something to distinguish on?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    DWORD stats = GetFileAttributesA( "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};server=localhost;database=NorthWindDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;" );
    cout << stats << endl;
}
```

prints 4294967295 - which is INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES. What does it do on your system?

Comment: thats because on your system it isnt valid. I.e. you dont have SQLServer 2008 with a database named NorthWindDB. As I said, on my system it returns 32

Comment: Are you implying that GetFileAttributesA opens a database connection if you supply a connection string???? Um, no, it doesn't, and the code I posted fails with INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES if I supply a valid connection string. Did you try the ACTUAL CODE I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps functions like [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963.aspx) can help you distinguish between files and connection strings? (not tested yet)

Also [SHLWAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559.aspx) provides a set of path functions which can be used to canonicalize the path or verify that a path seems to be valid.

Comment: Yea, I was looking at those functions, i dont see a "isvalidpath" function though

Comment: Another way would be to test with [_access()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy.aspx)…